# Use of Multiple locators to find a element in WebDriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I have a content under the div tag, i.e. h1 and h2 tags

```
 <div id="hp-main-menu-labels>
     <h1 id="hp-main-menu-label">Additional Info</h1>
     <h2 id="hp-main-menu-sub-label"></h2>
 </div>
```

I have used id and xpath as the locators seperately to inspect the element, but none of them were able to locate it.

Please suggest a method to locate them, share the method to use two locators in one statement,clicking on 'Additional Info' will do my work.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing the code that failed would be useful so we don't suggest solutions you may have already tried.  Also, you did not specify a language; the following are using Python.

This will assert if the element is currently visible on the page.  If this assert fails, the test will end.

```
self.assertTrue(self.is_element_present(By.ID, "hp-main-menu-label"))
```

This will assert that the text "Additional Info" is present within the "h1" element.

```
self.assertEqual("Additional Info", driver.find_element_by_css_selector("h1").text)
```

This will click on the HTML element with id "hp-main-menu-label"

```
driver.find_element_by_id("hp-main-menu-label").click()
```